# Casting every received packet as struct?

Tags: c#, performance, packet

What is the best performant solution to handle received data from socket, in a MMORPG game? Is it good to have something like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct LoginPacket
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int size;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int opcode;
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public int someOtherImportantOffsetInPacket;
}
```

And then when every packet is received I create the correct struct for the received packet, to access its information easier?
Or the best performant solution is if I just pass the `byte[]` to the function and use functions like `BitConverter.ToInt32` ? I know BitConverter is slow, but I already have my own class that does the same thing in a faster way.

Comment: Did you profile your code in actual usage scenario, or are you optimizing non-existent bottle-neck? You should be able to swap processing method in a few minutes and compare.

Comment: No, I didn't profile anything yet, just considering options

Comment: Then do whatever works and optimize it **IF** it becomes a bottle-neck.